# Q: ThreeJS Repeat Texture in threejs Editor Strange Behaviour

Tags: json, three.js

[enter link description here](https://sport.xbe.at/stadiumjson/index.html)As you can see in the attached images, the materials, doesn't repeat in all the area but only in a partial part (upper left). Any suggestion is very appreciated.

**I'm using [three js editor r.85](https://threejs.org/editor/)**

Image of the rendered file in threejs editor.
[image]

Image of the rendered file open [by normal html file.](https://sport.xbe.at/stadiumjson/index.html)
[image]

[Json file used (updated 05/28/2017)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cs1mj8pxdn1301m/scene.json)

Image (512x512)

[image: Image 512x512]

Comment: A guess is your texture is not a power-of-two in size. Check the console for messages.

Comment: I've attached the image that's 512x512.

Comment: Check the data url in the JSON and see if it is of the same size. Make sure the JSON file specifies your desired repeat values. Check the console messages.

Comment: In the Json the images are embedded:  "images": [
  {
   "uuid": "A4B17246-6B83-4AFC-AC95-7C559CECE0C0",
   "url": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN ...

Comment: (1) the green plaid one is "uuid": "69D30D2D-9E1F-498E-B8BD-3236FBEC5B19", and using an online data converter, it is 441 × 510. (2) the texture "uuid": "67623951-6CC7-4CD6-AC48-16EC0BE459CB" that uses that image needs to have wrapping changed to "wrap": [1000,1000].

Comment: Thanks for your help! this is the current situation: after updated the json file with power-of-two images and changed the wrapping param from 1001 to 1001) everything works fine, but if i uploaded the correct file in the editor online the problem still persist and the exported file has the 1001 instead of 1000.

Comment: If you can show that the editor is not handling exports correctly, then you can help by filing a three.js bug report. You should also create a simple JSON file with one plane geometry and one data texture that duplicates the problem.

Comment: Using a plane geometry created inside the editor and importing my texture  the map is correct :). I noticed that: "export scene" generate from my imported model (that's look ok after your suggestion) the problem persists (rendering and exporting) but using "publish" the json output is correct (i used the html+js in the published zip file to test).

Comment: Would you be willing to post a bug report at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues?

Comment: it's not necessary because after I tried the import/export scene, all working as a expetected!. I'll continue to use the editor and if happen again a fill a bug report. Thank you for your help!. Ps. I don't think was the cache because i empty every time before upload the file.